# How to Print a string to a specific character?

Tags: string, python-2.7

I have a file like this:

```
NA|polymerase|KC545393|Bundibugyo_ebolavirus|EboBund_112_2012|NA|2012|Human|Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo
NA|VP24|KC545393|Bundibugyo_ebolavirus|EboBund_112_2012|NA|2012|Human|Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo
NA|VP30|KC545393|Bundibugyo_ebolavirus|EboBund_112_2012|NA|2012|Human|Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo
```

I am trying to print this characters from each line:

```
polymerase|KC545393
VP24|KC545393
VP30|KC545393
```

How can I do this?
I tried this code:

```
for character in line:
    if character=="|":
        print line[1:i.index(j)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split each line by the `'|'` character; you can limit the splitting because you only need the first 3 columns:

```
elems = line.split('|', 3)
print '|'.join(elems[1:3])
```

The `print` line then takes the elements at index 1 and 2 and joins them together again using the `'|'` character to produce your desired output.

Demo:

```
>>> lines = '''\
... NA|polymerase|KC545393|Bundibugyo_ebolavirus|EboBund_112_2012|NA|2012|Human|Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo
... NA|VP24|KC545393|Bundibugyo_ebolavirus|EboBund_112_2012|NA|2012|Human|Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo
... NA|VP30|KC545393|Bundibugyo_ebolavirus|EboBund_112_2012|NA|2012|Human|Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo
... '''.splitlines(True)
>>> for line in lines:
...     elems = line.split('|', 3)
...     print '|'.join(elems[1:3])
... 
polymerase|KC545393
VP24|KC545393
VP30|KC545393
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you *know* that each line has at least two separators, you can use:

```
>>> s = 'this|is|a|string'
>>> s
'this|is|a|string'
>>> s[:s.find('|',s.find('|')+1)]
'this|is'
```

This finds the first `|` starting at the character position *beyond* the first `|` (i.e., it finds the *second* `|`) then gives you the substring up but not including to that point.

If it may *not* have two separators, you just have to be more careful:

```
s = 'blah blah'
result = s
if s.find('|') >= 0:
    if s.find('|',s.find('|')+1) >= 0:
        result = s[:s.find('|',s.find('|')+1)]
```

If that's the case, you'll probably definitely want it in a more general purpose function, something like:

```
def substringUpToNthChar(str,n,ch):
    if n < 1: return ""
    pos = -1
    while n > 0:
        pos = str.find(ch,pos+1)
        if pos < 0: return str
        n -= 1
    return str[:pos]
```

This will correctly handle the case where there's fewer separators than desired and will also handle (relatively elegantly) getting more than the first two fields.